# Aggregate data with sort and limit for each group in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

Group by with limit and sort for each group

```
db.getCollection('logSrcDest').aggregate(
     {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "src": "$srcId",
                "dest": "$destId",
                "account": "$account"
            },  
            total: { $sum : "$count" }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { total : -1 } },
    { $limit: 10 }
);
```

I have gone through this :
[mongo with limit and sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885047/mongodb-aggregate-sort-and-limit-within-group)
but i couldn't find the answer i required.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb aggregation pipeline how to limit a group push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594049/mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-how-to-limit-a-group-push)

Comment: @Styvane That's is different from what i am looking for

Comment: In that case, please show us sample documents with the expected result.

Comment: Please add  sample documents with the expected result to your question.

Comment: this is stored:
 {account=123,src=101,dest=202,count=10}
{ account=123,src=102,dest=203,count=13}
{account=123,src=104,dest=205,count=8}
{account=123,src=105,dest=206,count=12}

{ account=199,src=101,dest=202,count=19}
{ account=199,src=102,dest=203,count=23}
{account=199,src=103,dest=204,count=15}
{account=199,src=104,dest=205,count=28}
{account=199,src=105,dest=206,count=17}

Expected output in case of top 2 results:
{account=123,src=102,dest=203,count=13}
{account=123,src=105,dest=206,count=12}
{account=199,src=104,dest=205,count=28}
{account=199,src=102,dest=203,count=23}

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39764531/edit) link on your question. Also make sure you post a valid JSON document.

Comment: Please accept like this, i am unable to make json format for sample

Comment: Don't expect answers with poorly formatted question. Present question well then someone will give attention.

Comment: I think you are looking for this->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458107/limit-and-sort-each-group-by-in-mongodb-using-aggregation