# Mongo DB filtering data

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am working on a large dataset. Here there are multiple categories and values.
**Dataset**
 category, value
 A, 1
 B, 1
 A, 5
 A, 3
 A, 7
 B, 8
 A, 4
 B, 5
 B, 4
                                                                                From this, I have to get top 3 records from each category by value.
 Eg:
  category, value
   A, 8
   A, 7
   A, 5
   B, 8
   B, 5
   B, 4
I need this to be calculated in an efficient way.

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885047/mongodb-aggregate-sort-and-limit-within-group

Comment: Is there any solution using pymongo?

Comment: Python syntax is practically identical to the JavaScript syntax as shown in the answer there (albeit without the callbacks, depending on library). Your question however is far to obtuse to answer since it completely lacks demonstration of a valid document structure. So chances are the referenced answer is what you need. But if you believe not, then you need to improve your question.

Comment: Is there any way to do it using mongo aggregate? I am looking for a query which can do this.